# Is it possible to run X11 on Gitlab CI?

Tags: python, pyinstaller, gitlab-ci, x11, xorg

I'm trying to use pyinstaller to build a python game into a binary file. I had it working, but today I switched to using arcade instead of pygame. I can build this fine locally, but when pyinstaller is building, pyglet throws an exception saying that it can't find the X11 library. I installed xorg before building it, and not it throws an exception just saying that it can't connect to a display server. Here is the full traceback:

```py
$ pyinstaller -F biogame.spec
39 INFO: PyInstaller: 4.1
39 INFO: Python: 3.8.5
50 INFO: Platform: Linux-4.19.78-coreos-x86_64-with-glibc2.29
52 INFO: UPX is not available.
54 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['/builds/TabulateJarl8/biogame', '/builds/TabulateJarl8/biogame']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pyglet/__init__.py", line 337, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._module, name)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'Window'
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pyinstaller", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(run())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/PyInstaller/__main__.py", line 114, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/PyInstaller/__main__.py", line 65, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 720, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 667, in build
    exec(code, spec_namespace)
  File "biogame.spec", line 8, in <module>
    a = Analysis(['biogame.py'],
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 212, in __init__
    self.hookspath += list(entry_point.load()())
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2445, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2451, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/arcade/__init__.py", line 72, in <module>
    from .window_commands import close_window
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/arcade/window_commands.py", line 106, in <module>
    def get_window() -> pyglet.window.Window:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pyglet/__init__.py", line 343, in __getattr__
    __import__(import_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pyglet/window/__init__.py", line 1897, in <module>
    gl._create_shadow_window()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pyglet/gl/__init__.py", line 206, in _create_shadow_window
    _shadow_window = Window(width=1, height=1, visible=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pyglet/window/xlib/__init__.py", line 173, in __init__
    super(XlibWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pyglet/window/__init__.py", line 585, in __init__
    display = pyglet.canvas.get_display()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pyglet/canvas/__init__.py", line 94, in get_display
    return Display()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pyglet/canvas/xlib.py", line 123, in __init__
    raise NoSuchDisplayException('Cannot connect to "%s"' % name)
pyglet.canvas.xlib.NoSuchDisplayException: Cannot connect to "None"
```

I tried running `xinit` but that just errored out since there isn't any display, I tried `xrandr` but that failed as well, and I also tried doing `export DISPLAY=:0` which didn't help. Is there any way to get X11 running on Gitlab CI or is this impossible? Here's the section of my CI file that's relevant:

```yaml
ubuntubuild:
    image: ubuntu:latest
    stage: ubuntubuild
    before_script:
        - apt update
        - DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt install -y --no-install-recommends python3-pip python3-dev libjpeg-dev zlib1g-dev xorg
        - python3 -m pip install pyinstaller
        - python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt
    script:
        - pyinstaller -F biogame.spec
    artifacts:
        paths:
            - dist/biogame
```

UPDATE 1:

I managed to get Xvfb running but now pyglet throws an error saying `pyglet.gl.glx_info.GLXInfoException: pyglet requires an X server with GLX`. I've tried to tweak the Xvfb to be `Xvfb :1 -screen 0 1152x900x8 +extension GLX +render -noreset &`, and I've tried installing these packages: `mesa-common-dev libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dev libglu1-mesa-dev`

Comment: Take look at xvfb, it may suffice.

Comment: I tried adding `xvfb` to my things I'm installing, and then running `xvfb &`, but it just gives my this error `/usr/bin/bash: line 115: xvfb: command not found`

Comment: Nevermind, the command is just `Xvfb` with a capital X. Anyways, I did that with no error but the same error from pyglet came up. xvfb need to be configured or something? I also tried running `Xvfb :1 -screen 0 1152x900x8&` to see if that fixed it, and it also did not

Comment: Update, after doing `export DISPLAY=:1` along with the configured xvfb command, I got a new error `pyglet.gl.glx_info.GLXInfoException: pyglet requires an X server with GLX`

Comment: Try `Xvfb :1 -screen 0 1152x900x8 +extension GLX`. if that doesn't work, then your version of `Xvfb` probably doesn't have GLX compiled in, which means you need to compile it yourself

Comment: Also see this [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/410443/xvfb-glxgears-fails). One of the answers may have a solution for you

Comment: I cannot find anything at all on where the source for Xvfb is or how to compile it with GLX, I've been trying for almost 20 minutes now and can't find anything. Do you know how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally figured out how to fix it. I installed these packages and ran pyinstaller with `xvfb-run`

```sh
sudo apt install xorg-dev libglu1-mesa libgl1-mesa-dev xvfb libxinerama1 libxcursor1
xvfb-run -a -s "-screen 0 1400x900x24 +extension RANDR" -- pyinstaller -F biogame.spec
```

Comment: You should post this on gitlab forum for others to find

Comment: wait @Tabulate can you explain where the visuals are shown? Like you actually get graphics from gitlab.com pipeline UI?

Comment: @JustinMai No, or at least I wouldn't think you can. In my case, there wasn't actually ever something shown, it was just pyglet requiring a display server for some internal reason.

Comment: gotcha that makes sense -- wishful thinking :) thanks for your quick reply!

Comment: Just to clarify for other readers: [xvfb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb) stands for "**X** **V**irtual **F**rame**b**uffer". It's basically an X11 implementation that runs everything in-memory, so you can use it as a fake graphics server if you're running something in a headless server (like most CI pipeline runners).